# How to run X-code 5.0.0 on macbook pro 2015

Tags: xcode

When I install x-code 5 and open it, it tells me to update the x-code. Is there a way I can run x-code 5 on my mac?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please see [ask] for details on the best way to ask questions here.  You're missing some key info in your question and reading the Help Center will get you better answers (and avoid downvotes).

Comment: hi @junyoung ! depending on your macOS version, Xcode 5 could easily be not runnable on your Mac. Why would you not use xcode10 or 11 ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Xcode 5 dates back to 2012 which could be, relatively speaking, ancient history in Apple Developer Ecosystem timeline. Is there a strong reason for you to use the specific version? Kindly consider stating the same and it may be possible to get the needful done in a more recent and supported version of Xcode.